# Abelian Groups and orders

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I came across this question, and was wondering what the notation G[n : a] means. Is x the generator? Any comments/explanations will be of great help. The question I found was:

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $a\in G$. For $n≥1$, let $G[n:a] := \{x\in G:x^n =a\}$.

(a) Show that $G[n: a]$ is either empty or equal to $αG[n] := \{αg : g \in G[n]\}$, for some $α∈G$. (Recall: $G[n]:=\{x\in G:x^n =1\}$.)

(b) If $G$ is cyclic of order $m$, prove that:

$|G[n:a]| = (n,m)$ if $\text{Ord}(a)\mid(m/(n, m))$, OR
$0$ otherwise.

Comment: The question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521797/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-and-let-a∈g-for-n≥1-let-gna-x∈gxn-a-show.